# Inexpensive online localization service

Tags: localization

We use a desktop software to localize our .NET application. It can export the localizable strings to XLS, that I send to our users who help us to translate the program strings.

All is OK if only one user is involved into the translation process with a certain language. But if two users start to localize the program to the same language - we face with translation collisions.

I thought to start using SVN to host our translation XLS files, but maybe someone could recommend me an inexpensive online service that allows us to avoid using SVN (cause it requires some learning curve for our customers).

Comment: Have you consider using google docs? Many contributors can work on the same file at the same time and no svn knowledge is required.

Comment: Putty, thanks for the answer! I didn't think that I can use google docs for this. I'll try. I need to check whether I can revert to a previous document version if someone will screw the part of the hole documents.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider crowdin.net.
It is really comfortable workflow for localization project.
P.S. prices are acceptable by the way.